# MAMP ImageMagick PHP Command Line

Tags: php, imagemagick, mamp

I installed MAMP and activated ImageMagick. I am trying to execute a few simple command line functions on an image directly with-in the PHP code - like resize etc and output a new image file, but I can't get it working. Nothing happens. I know ImageMagick is installed and working b/c I got a few things working earlier, I know I can figure everything else out, as soon as I can get ImageMagick executing within the PHP. Here is what I have...

```
<?PHP

    exec('convert -resize 100x100 original.jpg output.jpg');

?>
```

The `original.jpg` is in the same root directory as this `index.php` file.

If someone could point me in the right direction here, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your command to this and it should show you some errors:

```
$array=array();
echo "<pre>";
exec("convert original.jpg -resize 100x100 output.jpg 2>&1", $array); 
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>"; 
echo "</pre>";
```

The input image should come directly after the convert. If you are using V7 you will need to change convert to magick

Comment: Thanks very much for the help - here is what im getting...
Array
(
    [0] => sh: convert: command not found
)

1

Comment: Looks like IM is not installed? It was producing thumbs earlier though? Maybe that was iMagick

Comment: If is add a dash to -convert I get a long array
(
    [0] => allexport       off
    [1] => braceexpand     on
    [2] => emacs           on
    [3] => errexit         off
    [4] => errtrace        off
    [5] => functrace       off
    [6] => hashall         on
    [7] => histexpand      on
    [8] => history         on
    [9] => ignoreeof       off
    [10] => interactive-comments on
   ....

Comment: Have you tried changing convert to magick? Also
echo "<pre>";
system("convert -version"); // or magick  
echo "</pre>";